# snipeit on kubernetes not running

Tags: laravel, docker, kubernetes

i am trying to deploy snipe-it on k8s cluster

i have running mysql on kubernetes

i want to deploy snipe-it application on kubernetes

my yaml file is like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: snipeit
  labels:
    app: snipeit
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: snipeit
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: snipeit-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: snipeit
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: snipeit
  labels:
    app: snipeit
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: snipeit
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: snipeit
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: snipe/snipe-it
        name: snipeit
        env:
        - name: DB_CONNECTION
          value: mysql
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: mysql
        - name: DB_USERNAME
          value: root
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: snipeit
        - name: APP_URL
          value: url
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: snipeit
        volumeMounts:
        - name: snipeit-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: snipeit-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: snipeit-pv-claim
```

this is not working

image i am using is from docker hub :

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/snipe/snipe-it
```

github snipe-it : `https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it`

container start running but i logged inside container and check var/www/html but no content there

Comment: You have a PVC there but where does your PV come from? You either need to manually provision a [persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), depends on your environment what you have available, or, preferably, use dynamic provisioning via defining a [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

Comment: okay i will check at company thankyou so much for answer. thankyou..i think got mistake

Comment: it's still not working ..i have change storage class as per digital ocean guide line ..but pod "crashloopbackoff" error

Comment: OK, that's already some progress. Suggest to try one of the things I put together in http://troubleshooting.kubernetes.sh/#image-issue to debug this one.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas i am so sorry ...there was mistake in my config ...i change it ..it's up and running ....Thankyou so much for help..Have a great day a head..Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. What I'd now suggest is that you answer the question yourself, below (and accept the answer as the correct one). Why? This is how SO works, you share your experience and many after you benefit from it.

Comment: sure as you advice.... i am new to k8s learning it & new to devops wolrd.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: snipe-it-config
data:
  # Mysql Parameters
  MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR: "address"
  MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT: "3306"
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "snipeit"
  MYSQL_USER: "user"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"

  # Email Parameters
  # - the hostname/IP address of your mailserver
  MAIL_PORT_587_TCP_ADDR: "<smtp-host>"
  #the port for the mailserver (probably 587, could be another)
  MAIL_PORT_587_TCP_PORT: "587"
  # the default from address, and from name for emails
  MAIL_ENV_FROM_ADDR: "noreply@mydomain.com"
  MAIL_ENV_FROM_NAME: "Snipe-IT"
  # - pick 'tls' for SMTP-over-SSL, 'tcp' for unencrypted
  MAIL_ENV_ENCRYPTION: "tls"
  # SMTP username and password
  MAIL_ENV_USERNAME: "<smtp-username>"
  MAIL_ENV_PASSWORD: "<smtp-password>"

  # Snipe-IT Settings
  APP_ENV: "production"
  APP_DEBUG: "false"
  APP_KEY: "key"
  APP_URL: "http://127.0.0.1:80"
  APP_TIMEZONE: "Asia/Kolkata"
  APP_LOCALE: "en"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: snipeit
  labels:
    app: snipeit
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: snipeit
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: snipeit
  labels:
    app: snipeit
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: snipeit
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: snipeit
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: snipe/snipe-it
        name: snipeit
        envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: snipe-it-config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: snipeit
        volumeMounts:
        - name: snipeit-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/snipeit
      volumes:
      - name: snipeit-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: snipeit-pv-claim
```

instead of using configmap i was adding enviroment variables and parameters in deployment section...so just added config map and smoothly it's up and running